# Does an enum in MySQL need to be NOT NULL?

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have this:

```
ALTER TABLE asdf ADD field ENUM('Y', 'N') DEFAULT 'N';
```

Is putting a NOT NULL on the end necessary as it can only be Y and N?

EDT: based on comments, if I know the software always sets it to 'N' or 'Y' and is hardcoded in then is it OK to leave it off or could it still potentially become null some how.

Answer (score 24):

MySQL will allow the value to be NULL if you do not specify `NOT NULL` in the column definition.

Here's a quick test:

```
mysql> create table test (id serial, field ENUM('Y','N') DEFAULT 'N');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (field) VALUES ('Y');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (field) VALUES ('N');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test () VALUES ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (field) VALUES (NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (field) VALUES ('Invalid');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                    |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'field' at row 1 | 
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+----+-------+
| id | field |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Y     | 
|  2 | N     | 
|  3 | N     | 
|  4 | NULL  | 
|  5 |       | 
+----+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So MySQL does respect the default value, but also allows NULLs. (Interestingly, it will truncate invalid values and allow blank strings as well, but that's a different issue)

Answer (score 12):

To set a default value 'N' for the column with a NOT NULL constraint, do this:

```
ALTER TABLE asdf ADD field ENUM('N', 'Y') NOT NULL;
```

Explanation: According to the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html):

> If an ENUM column is declared NOT NULL, its default value is the first element of the list of permitted

Answer (score 4):

In ENUM data type, if you do not declare NOT NULL then it gives the default value NULL. However, if you declare NOT NULL then it gives the first value from the ENUM.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Ian Clelland is very good but more details :

```
   mysql> CREATE TABLE en1(en enum('A','B') DEFAULT 'A',sets set('A','B') DEFAULT '
    B');
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

    mysql> INSERT INTO en1 VALUES();
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

    mysql> INSERT INTO en1 VALUES(NULL,NULL);
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

    mysql> SELECT * FROM en1;
    +------+------+
    | en   | sets |
    +------+------+
    | A    | B    |
    | NULL | NULL |
    +------+------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> CREATE TABLE en2(en enum('A','B') DEFAULT 'A' NOT NULL,sets set('A','B')
    DEFAULT 'B' NOT NULL);
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

    mysql> INSERT INTO en2 VALUES(NULL,NULL);
    ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'en' cannot be null
```

Answer (score -1):

Nope, not necessary at all, it'll just default it to 'N' as you're probably expecting.

Edit: Commenter made me go off and test this, you should add `not null` unless you want null to be a valid value. Having `default 'N'` will default it to N if you leave the column out of your insert SQL, but if you set the value to null in the insert or update it will insert a row with null for the value, as you might not want.

Comment: Reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html ("If an ENUM column is declared to allow NULL, the NULL value is a legal value for the column, and the default value is NULL.") I believe one could successfully insert NULL in this column.