# How to remove enum error: enum(0)

Tags: mysql

Enum not accepting any value.I tried almost everything but enum not working
always give error:

> Error#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\'0\'' , `Status` ENUM(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT
>   '\'0\'' , `Dat' at line 1w

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does an enum in MySQL need to be NOT NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058954/does-an-enum-in-mysql-need-to-be-not-null)

Comment: Post your `CREATE TABLE` statement.